# SQL: Problems translating recursive connect by Statement for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to translate the following oracle sql, which inserts 1000 rows with incremental values into a table:

```
insert into tableName (col1, col2, col3)
    select 'AN' || (1000000 + ROWNUM), 'EXT' || (9000000 + ROWNUM), ROWNUM
    from dual
    Connect By  ROWNUM <= 1000 ;
```

For Postgres support, i know i can substitute ROWNUM with ROW_NUMBER() OVER (), but i'm really getting a headache about translating the connect by statement. I have read about CTEs but i don't get how i can use this with an insert statement.

Does anyone know how to write this statement for postgresql? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a series and just use that:

```
insert into tableName (col1, col2, col3)
    select 'AN' || (1000000 + g.n), 'EXT' || (9000000 + g.n), g.n
    from generate_series(1, 1000) g(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `generate_series`.

```
 select 'AN' || (1000000 + ROWNUM), 'EXT' || (9000000 + ROWNUM),
 ROWNUM from generate_series(1,10000) as rownum ;
```